# Controlling children with higher frequency

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, government

In my book* the government is using higher frequncies  [that only children can hear](https://www.yahoo.com/beauty/try-it-can-you-hear-these-sounds-only-young-112627654778.html) to control them. The government is using smart devices ( mobile phones, tablets, computers) to first talk with children and gain their trust. After they have their trust they tell the children to sabotage peoples day that are against the government. Imagine you have a big meeting that day and your kid breaks something in the house so you can't go to work or pulling the plug when you want to open an anti-government website (small stuff like that).

As they get a little older they start telling them ideologies and how they should behave.

The first time  they start taking with a child it will be about some normal stuff so if the child tells her parents they will think it is an imaginary friend so nobody will suspect something like that. The problem is that you have a limited time period to influence the children because they will after a while stop to hear the frequency.

When should you start talking with kids and how much could you influence them like this?

*I am not writing a book

Comment: Your username in combination with the question is unsettling.

Comment: Consider whether 1) it's universally true that all children can hear high frequencies that all adults can't; and 2) whether speech at those high frequencies would be intelligible. For instance, standard telephone audio clips to a frequency range of (IIRC) 300 - 3400 Hz, or about 2 orders of magnitude. But (again IIRC) human hearing is closer to log than linear, so to get the same dynamic range you might have to transform it to the 10K-100K range.

Comment: Children talking to their parents is actually a huge problem. Imaginary friends don't teach them new stuff, and whenever the kids learn something new, parents (at least I do) will wonder who taught them that. Worse, parents discuss that sort of thing among each other. When multiple children learn the same thing in mysterious ways, something is up. Even if they can't figure out the source, they can actively invalidate the ideologies the government puts in their head. It is, after all not that hard to figure out what they are. Children can be brutally honest at the age they are still susceptible

Comment: On a less serious note: Children don't need to to be told by the government to ruin their parents' day. That sort of behavior is hardwired into their brains. ;)

Comment: My hearing is worse then it was when I was a child, but I still can hear those higher frequencies... If my computer starts talking to my child where I should not be able to hear? Let's put it this way, the anti-vax movement are but baby steps compared to this.

Comment: @jamesqf Didn't think about that, Theraot answer is a good solution for that.
Flummox I can first test if an adult can hear that easily by using mandatory "health checks" that cover hearing and other related stuff

Comment: Also consider that consumer speakers are usually designed to produce output in the normal auditory range. How exactly does the government ensure that the non standard frequency outputs produce clear sound?

Comment: @nzaman that would be easy, you have government regulations for a lot of products, why not for speakers too

Comment: @Sazanami: Don't know about others, but I certainly learned a lot of new stuff from books.  Which leads to a bigger question: even if the government (or somebody) tries to indoctrinate children, what guarantee is there that the indoctrination will take?  As for instance, from earliest childhood I was indoctrinated with the beliefs & societal mores of a particular religion, yet have rejected (most of) them from my mid-teens onwards.

Comment: @jamesqf Exactly. Indoctrination requires isolation (either physical or mental) from books, internet, family, friends and other sources of information that contradict the worldview you're trying to impart on the subject. In the case of the OP's scenario, being able to secretively talk to a child is simply insufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When should you start talking with kids (...)?

Parents should start talking with their offspring before birth, the fetus responds to sounds starting around 23 weeks into pregnancy.

> how much could you influence them like this?

The baby will be able to recognize the voices, sounds and melodies. Note that the baby would not recognize or have recollection of any spoken words... not only because it is not creating permanent memories yet, but because of the acoustics of the womb.

---

***What? Do you mean to talk to them using a high pitch voice, inaudible to adults, to indoctrinate them into your crazy regime?***

Well, in that case: Never.

Speech is not only harder to understand on the higher pitch, but you do not really want to target the speech centers of the brain at all.

---

Here is what you do:

Start by using the tone as reward system. Placing it in multiple applications and in particular in video games that the kids play, and set to sound when thing work correctly. For example, beep when the kid enters a new area, when solves a puzzle, etc. Bonus points if the parents also praise them for these things.

The idea here is to have the kid associate that doing that behavior is a good thing. And that they hear that tone when they do a good thing.

Eventually the kids will have a dopamine boost when they hear these tones. This is what you want.

Even when the ability of the children to hear those tones goes away, the positive reinforcement they had with the places and things where they did hear them does not.

---

You can do a bit more by using melodies. You reward specific actions that follow the behavior you want using melodies on those high frequency tones.

You can use those melodies in the real world to direct the kids. Hide them in other media (like actual music, for example) or in news reports, or have them play in the background in certain locations.

Humans can recognize melodies even if played in a different pitch (bearing the occasional amusia). This means that you can use even audible versions of these melodies. Although this increases the risk of starting a conversation about them.

---

You want to start this process when the kid is three years old, at this point the child can start handling a tablet or similar device, is willing to explore and experiment, doesn’t really question the world, and a lot of people have their oldest memory around this age.

Comment: Thank for the idea :D the reward system using melodies should work

Comment: Please, don't give Big Brother further ideas. Thanks. Signed: Emmanuel Goldstein

Comment: This is a great answer.  You took a seemingly unworkable question premise and made a plausibly workable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Frequency is a physical quantity which exists in nature. Pitch is a sensation which exists in the mind. The relationship between sound frequency and perceived pitch is logarithmic -- the best example of the [Weber-Fechner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber%E2%80%93Fechner_law) law.

The point here is that although young humans can hear (not well, but they can) sounds up to 19–20 kHz, which is about 3 to 4 kHz above the 16 kHz accessible to middle-aged humans, the difference is much much smaller in terms of pitch -- only a little more than a major third, less than perfect fourth. You cannot squeeze speech in such a small interval; you cannot make music: imagine a melody which can only go from C to E...

Moreover, while it's true that very young humans *can* hear sounds about one major third (and very very young humans even a perfect fourth or may be a little more) above what middle-aged humans can, they hear them *very faintly*. Any kind of regular audible sound will mask out those faint tones.

Comment: Thank you, now i have to find a new plot for my "book" :/

Answer (score 0):

Governments have far more effective ways to control children (and through them entire future generations).
It's called the public school system in combination with Child Protective Services (or its equivalent in other countries).

Train/indoctrinate children to report/snitch on their parents for any anti-government activities (rewards in toys, candy, whatever works).
Parents get arrested, children put in foster homes or orphanages, problem sold.